# Who suppressed the Book of Jubilees and why?

Tags: ancient-history, jews, bible

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilees) says the Book of Jubilees was suppressed in 4th century CE:

> The Book of Jubilees (Hebrew: ספר היובלים Sepher hayYobelim),
>   sometimes called Lesser Genesis (Leptogenesis), is an ancient Jewish
>   religious work of 50 chapters, considered one of the pseudepigrapha by
>   Protestant, Roman Catholic, and Eastern Orthodox Churches.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilees) Jubilees
>   is considered canonical by the Ethiopian Orthodox Church as well as
>   Jews in Ethiopia, where it is known as the Book of Division (Ge'ez:
>   Mets'hafe Kufale).
>
> It was well known to Early Christians, as evidenced by the writings of
>   Epiphanius, Justin Martyr, Origen, Diodorus of Tarsus, Isidore of
>   Alexandria, Isidore of Seville, Eutychius of Alexandria, John Malalas,
>   George Syncellus, and George Kedrenos. **It was so thoroughly suppressed
>   in the 4th century that no complete Hebrew, Greek or Latin version has
>   survived.** There is conjecture among western biblical scholars that
>   Jubilees may be a rework of material found in the canonical books of
>   Genesis and Exodus.

My question is:

*Do we know who suppressed this book and why?*

*And how do we know it was intentionally suppressed as opposed to getting lost like so much ancient literature?*

Comment: Dear Downvoter, please tell me your reasons...

Comment: clearly, a member of the same consipiracy who suppressed the book.

Comment: @DVK Oh my, this is getting scary...

Comment: There is no shortage of [pseudepigrapha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Old_Testament_pseudepigrapha), and having to constantly copy them all (since writing materials decay quite rapidly over time) would have been quite a monumental undertaking, which is why determining canonical lists was very important in a time when resources were notoriously scarce.

Comment: @Lucian Excellent point!  Ancient texts were mostly written on papyrus and papyrus is not very durable. Most of the ancient texts were have lost -- both religious and secular -- simply weren't copied often enough for one copy to survive. (A large part of what did survive, survived because the single remaining papyrus copy was copied onto vellum/parchment during the medieval period.) You don't need anyone actively suppressing a work -- two thousand years of indifference is sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

The rabbis of the first centuries A.C. had mixed opinions regarding apocryphical books (״ספרים חיצוניים״). Though some maintained that these books were holy (though not to be read by laymen), others claimed that the reading of these books was enough to condemn one as a heretic.

The Book of Jubilees may have been especially suppressed as it espoused a solar based calendar, in contrast to the dominant view supported by the Pharisees, according to which the months are lunar based.

Comment: One other interesting factoid: The Book of Jubilees forbids lying with one's wife on the Sabbath, while rabbinical sources suggest scholars should refrain from intercourse on all days *but* the Sabbath.

Comment: People following both the rabbinical precepts and the Book of Jubilees taboo have had unhappy and unfruitful mariages.

Comment: @NathanielBubis The latter part of your post - not quite. It's not that they "should refrain" on other days (or rather nights), it's that they have a specific obligation on the Sabbath.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Donald H. Akenson](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=40E8am9SlwgC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=book%20of%20jubilees%20suppression&source=bl&ots=AjK3gNDVvU&sig=maYuxoSmaJIkw8lRRcJG2-Ltb0s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZvvFUcvAJMbbsgajx4C4Bg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=book%20of%20jubilees%20suppression&f=false) (p. 146), it was suppressed by the later Rabbis.

Comment: I have a theory (read: hypothesis) that Hebrew scripture canonical disputes are largely the result of a disparity between the Essenes (and similar communities, such as the Qumran community if they weren't Essenes) and other Jews. The early Christian communities were heavily influenced by the Essenes (and related communities), so they favored books such as Jubilees and Enoch. Later, when many books were called into question by the proliferation of Gnostic works and Christian pseudepigrapha, the Christian community at large thought they would be more well founded...

Comment: (cont.)...if they sided with their Jewish contemporaries in regards to the Hebrew scriptures. Those Jews had inherited their ancestors' views of the texts favored by the Essenes (that they should be rejected).

Comment: Well, it is an interesting question why it falls out of favour in both communities at about the same time...

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for the suppression of Jubilees. People call Jubilees pseudepigrapha but it claims Mosaic authorship given to him by YHWH on Mount Sinai.  That would in fact make it authoritative and part of the Torah not outside of Torah or extra Biblical!   The calendar in it was against the Babylonian calendar the post exilic Jews kept, which was a corruption of the Biblical calendar.  Jubilees also predicts the Jews going wrong following the moon and losing 10 days per year, which is exactly the case!  Also as to historical timing of events, Jubilees in some instances is different than the Mesoretic text of the Hebrew Scriptures which Jubilees oldest copy is over 1100 years older than the Mesoretic text.  Also the dates in Jubilees validates the dates in the LXX which is also older and more reliable that the Mesoretic text.  People do not realize that the Torah keeping faith of Mosaic Israel, and post exilic Judaism is 2 completely different things.  So much to say but I hope that helps.

Comment: Do you know why, in the Torah, a month is called חודש chodesh (as in Exodus 12:2)? Because that comes from the root חדש chadash, "new," meaning that it's tied to the appearance of the new moon. In a solar-based calendar there's nothing "new" about the beginning of any month. So much for "going wrong following the moon."